# A question about "JSON 2 Table using VueJS"

Tags: json, vue.js

This is my first time to use vue.js, I'm following the youtube video: https://youtu.be/qOK6bOflZv0

This video showed how to use an external JSON and put data in the table.

I believed my code is the same as the video, but I could not get the object like the video from an external JSON.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container mt-4" id="app">
        <a v-bind:href="href">{{message}}</a>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in users">
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'test',
            href: 'javascript:void(0)',
            users: []
        },
        mouted: function() {

            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data;
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

This is my result: the table should loop the JSON (or at least, the console should show my object, but either is blank.

[image]

This is the screen snap from the video, it has already shown the data in the table.
[image]

Really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: What result are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I have already uploaded two pics in my post.

Comment: is the response of type array ? because as far as I know it will be of type object

Comment: it's a typo, the hook function is called `mounted` instead of `mouted`